# Executable file when running is showing errors but the python file from which it is converted is running and working fine

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, executable

I had converted Python file to executable file and I wan to run executable file but it is showing error. python file was working fine without any errors.

EXE file error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VeerP.py", line 101, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\ensemble\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py", line 56, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\tree\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "sklearn\tree\_criterion.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.tree._criterion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special.cython_special'
[19216] Failed to execute script VeerP
```

Comment: What are you using to wrap your Python program in an executable? It's not obvious and it does matter.

Comment: I'm using PyInstaller for wraping Python program to an executable file

Comment: Wrapping a Python program in an executable is more complex than you might imagine, particularly if it has extensive dependencies. This may be what `pyinstaller` calls a "hidden import". The `pyinstaller` documentation has a very useful section called *When things go wrong*. I suggest you work through it.

Comment: @BoarGules Could you please elaborate, how to call a "hidden import" with some code?

Comment: The code you need to do this is called a `.spec` file, as the docs explain. Please read them. How to deal with hidden imports is too long and complicated for me to summarize here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using different Python interpreters in one and the other. When running from the command line, try

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 myfile.py
```

Then try

```
./myfile.py
```

with

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

being the first line in the file. (The actual path might be something different on your machine.)